# How can I integrate the Ordinary differential equation using odeint from scipy.integrate?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy

I am trying to integrate function defined as f in the code using odeint from scipy.
The function f takes theta, t, and K as arguments, which are defined below the function f.
y is the result, for which I am getting error. The reason for error is theta which is 2 dimensional. I am not able to perform integration. Could somebody help me in this ?

```
import numpy as np
import random
from scipy.integrate import odeint
```

`f` is function to be integrated

```
def f(theta, t, K):
    global N   
    tau = 1.5  
    dtheta = np.zeros([T,N], float)  
    for i in range(N):  
        s = 0.  
        for j in range(i+1,N):  
            s = s + np.sin(theta[t-tau,j] - theta[t,i])  
        dtheta[t,i] = K*s  
    return dtheta  

# Number of nodes
N = 10
# Constant
K = 1.0
# Number of time steps 
T = 100
t = np.linspace(0, T, 100, endpoint=False)
theta = np.zeros([T,N], float)
```

Uniformly generates random number

```
for i in range(N):
    theta[0,i] = random.uniform(-180, 180)
```

Integrate function `f` using `odeint` from `scipy`

```
y = odeint(f, theta, t, args=(K,))
print y
```

Comment: @SilentGhost it's in the title

Comment: @gokcehan: if you understand what it means, why don't you post an explanation, instead of snarky comment?

Comment: @SilentGhost I wasn't trying to be a jerk it's just I didn't see the question at first too. I don't know the answer to the question..

Comment: @gokcehan: but do you understand it? I see some code where function in question is used. I don't know what _integrating using `odeint` from `scipy`_ means.

Comment: @SilentGhost well I'm just speculating here but apparently `scipy.integrate.odeint` is a function to integrate (mathematically) a function and he wants to know how to use it on his function `f`. Hope he can join the conversation at some point..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write

```
y = odeint(f, theta.ravel(), t, args=(K,))
```

and

```
def f(theta, t, K):
    global N
    theta = theta.reshape(T, N)
    ...
    return dtheta.ravel()
```

Comment: Tanks a lot buddy. After impelementing your idea of reshaping and flattening the array does not impart any error, but it does not yield correct result.

Comment: It works, and solves a differential equation theta' = f(theta). You have made some different mistake if you do not get the results you expect.